# Better way to iterate XML and update in powershell?

Tags: xml, powershell

I got this to work, but I am not happy with the result, and I am wondering how this can be done better.

**XML**

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration version="3">
  <library>
    <default-theme>None</default-theme> 
    <export-path>Default</export-path>
    <caching-enabled>True</caching-enabled>
  </library>
</configuration>
```

**PS**

```
Function ModifyConfigFile()
{
  $xml = New-Object -TypeName XML
  $xml.Load($FilePath)
  $item = $xml.configuration.library 
  $item.ChildNodes.Item(1)."#text" = "Modify-Test"
  $xml.Save($NewFilePath)
}
```

I was trying to update the "export-path" text node, which this code **does** do, but the code is dependent on me **knowing** that this node is the 2nd item in the Child node of its parent library.

Is there a cleaner way?

Or at the very least a way for me to verify that I am updating the node that I want "export-path"?

Comment: `$xml.configuration.library.'export-path'='Modify-Test'`?

Comment: Oh man! That is one of the first things I tried, but it was giving an error, because I didnt put the export-path in quotes like you did! I have learned the hard way about Powershell and escaping things, looks like I am continuing to learn! Thanks for showing me the way! ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a more 'powershell' approach to loading the file, and incorporating PetSerAl comment

```
[xml]$doc = gc $filePath
$doc.configuration.library.'export-path' = "Modify-Test"
$doc.Save($filePath)
```